# Firefox won't show favicon on a tab

Tags: firefox, chromium, favicon

I tried nearly all answers from other SO questions I found. Accessing the favicon by itself works, Vimperator shows it when I `:open` that URL, but FF tab with said page has no favicon. Screenshot:

[image: favicon not showing though being present and correct]

Code:

```
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="img/animated_favicon.gif">
```

Further info:

1. Code is between `head` tags.
2. Code is OK at least for Chromium: favicon shows there.
3. Path to image is correct.
4. Image exists and has proper resolution / format. Firefox can show it.
5. Specifying path with / or without changes nothing (in both FF and Chromium).
6. Restarting FF did not help, with deleting today's history also.
7. Copying icon file to root folder did not help.
8. It's not cache, reload with cache bypassing changes nothing.

EDIT after @Lin's answer:

1. Image can be found at both paths: `http://host.domain/path/img/favicon.ico` and `file://root/directory/path/img/favicon.ico`.
2. Image is NOT loaded by Firefox (no request is even made, both FireBug and WebDebugger tool from FF do not show any such request). Again, on both paths.
3. Chromium displays favicon even when served as `file://...`.
4. FF sees favicon on hosted file when asked to group tabs, it's displayed: 
   [image: FF group cards UI partial screenshot], but even then it's NOT shown on tab.

What am I doing wrong or what am I unaware of?

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check point 3 again. Cheers.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help as well. Thank you @lin, still.